# How to use the CURRENT_DATE function in a hibernate criterion?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql, criteria

I want to translate the following HQL into Criteria notation:

```
from Deal
where CURRENT_DATE between startDate and endDate
```

I tried using Restrictions.between but it doesn't recognize current_date

```
Criteria c = session().createCriteria(Deal.class)
   .add(Restrictions.between("CURRENT_DATE", "startDate", "endDate");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the UGLY java Calendar!

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Date currentDate = c.getTime();

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Deal.class)
.add(Restrictions.gt("startDate", currentDate))     
.add(Restrictions.lt("endDate", currentDate));
```